# getStoreCategories() to get categories by ids

Tags: magento

I would like to get an array of categories for my magento store.

I need to use following unit for my website to work:

```
$categories = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', true, true);
```

However this lists all categories.

I would like to select categories that are important for me. I think I could do that by selecting ids of the categories or names of the categories but I don't know how to do it.

Could anybody help me please?

Comment: which categories do you want ?

Comment: what is the base to select? name, slug, category id? If I could use any of these I could select the correct categories I guess

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an array with category ids like this:

```
$ids = array(6,8,99);
```

You can get the category objects like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $ids);
```

if you want only active categories add this line also

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function and just pass category Id:

```
function getCategoryData($_categoryId=null) {
  // For category Collection
  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId);

  // For product Collection category wise
  $prodCollection = $category->getProductCollection();

  return $prodCollection;
}
```